# Reloading a window in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a couple PyQt Windows setup, and am using a ListWidget in each. I want it so that at the click of a button on a certain window, it would reload the ListWidget with the new info(sort of update the data). Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on here, some source code would have been useful...

The reloading bit:

```
def reloadList(info):
    # info is a list of strings
    listwidget.clear()
    listwidget.addItems(info)
```

The button callback:

```
btn.clicked.connect(reloadList)
```

Not sure that answers your question, but if you give more detailed info, I might be able to give better answers ;-)